# Adding a crontab - syntax

Tags: cron, cat

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 0 * * * /path/to/cron/job"; } | crontab -
```

I took this line from the net, to add a new cron job. It works well and good. I got the doubts,

1) Why do we need the curly brackets (or can we use single quotes) here,

```
{ cat; echo "0 0 * * * /path/to/cron/job"; }
```

2) And why do we need the `cat;` command here?

3) `crontab -`. If my understanding is correct, does `-` get replaced by the output of the previous command in the pipeline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Why do we need the curly brackets

Because you need to pipe both the output of `cat` and the output of `echo` to `crontab -`.  Without the curly braces you can't assemble the output of the two commands in a single pipe.

> (or can we use single quotes) here

Nope.  `... | 'cat; echo "0 0 * * * /path/to/cron/job"' | ...` means "pipe to an executable named `cat; echo "0 0 * * * /path/to/cron/job"`".  That doesn't make sense.

> 2) And why do we need the `cat;` command here?

You don't.  You could have written the same thing more efficiently as:

```
{ crontab -l; echo '0 0 * * * /path/to/cron/job'; } | crontab -
```

> 3) `crontab -`. If my understanding is correct, does `-` get replaced by the output of the previous command in the pipeline?

Yes, but that's because `crontab` specifically supports that.  Using `-` to mean `stdin` and / or `sdtout` is a convention understood by many commands, but it's just that, a convention.  It isn't mandated by the shell, like, say, `>file` or `| command`.